# Not getting proper text when I implement Google ML OCR Tesseract in my android project

Tags: android, tesseract

```
I am trying to implement Google ML OCR Tesseract in my android project and i am getting some random text from the picture I have clicked. Following is my code:
```

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
private lateinit var tessBaseAPI: TessBaseAPI
private lateinit var imageView: ImageView
private lateinit var textView: TextView
private val requestImageCapture = 1
private val takePicture =
registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->

```
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val resultInfo = result.data?.extras?.get("data")
            val imageBitmap = result.data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap?
            imageBitmap?.let {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(it)
                recognizeText(it)
            }
        }
    }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
    val captureButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.captureButton)

    copyLanguageDataToInternalStorage()
    initTesseract()

    captureButton.setOnClickListener {
        dispatchTakePictureIntent()
    }
}

private fun initTesseract() {
    val datapath = "${filesDir}/tesseract/"
    val dir = File(datapath)
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs()
    }
    val datafilepath = "${datapath}/tessdata/"
    val filesDir = File(datafilepath)
    if (!filesDir.exists()) {
        filesDir.mkdirs()
    }
    Log.d("dataPath", "data: $datapath")
    tessBaseAPI = TessBaseAPI()
    tessBaseAPI.init(datapath, "eng")
}

private fun copyLanguageDataToInternalStorage() {
    Log.d("test", "testing")
    try {
        val assetManager = assets
        val inputStream = assetManager.open("tesseract/tessdata/eng.traineddata")
        val outputStream =
            FileOutputStream(File(filesDir, "tesseract/tessdata/eng.traineddata"))

        inputStream.use { input ->
            outputStream.use { output ->
                input.copyTo(output)
            }
        }

    } catch (e: IOException) {

        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        takePicture.launch(takePictureIntent)
    }
}

private fun recognizeText(bitmap: Bitmap) {
    tessBaseAPI.setImage(bitmap)
    val recognizedText = tessBaseAPI.getUTF8Text()
    textView.text = recognizedText
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    tessBaseAPI.end()
}
```

}

```
and i am getting this as text

`m”;-.v__m-~_;;;;;;§'F"WWW If?`

Can Someone tell me where i am doing wrong in getting text from capturing a picture from the phone
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not describe how did included Tesseract into your project (via wrapper or directly?), but tesseract `setImage` expects a Leptonica PIX object for recognition, not a bitmap. Please check if this is not the reason for your problem (e.g. via tesseract variable `tessedit_write_images`).

I am not an Android developer, but the logic of the `initTesseract` function is suspicious - it just creates a directory structure without calling `copyLanguageDataToInternalStorage` - this could cause you will try to init tesseract API without any language file, so API will not be inited...